# Can not call vba for Button

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this:
[How to create a dynamic button in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549586/how-to-create-a-dynamic-button-in-excel)

It creates a button and ties a macro to it and works well.

I can run it as a stand alone macro but if I try to call it

```
Call CreateDynamicButton
```

Nothing happens, is it possible to call it?

Thanks

```
Sub CreateDynamicButton()
Dim MyR As Range, MyB As OLEObject
Dim MyR_T As Long, MyR_L As Long


    Set MyR = Range("C110") 'just an example - you get that from your own script
    MyR_T = MyR.Top         'capture positions
    MyR_L = MyR.Left        '...
    'create button
    Set MyB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)

    'set main button properties
    With MyB
        .Name = "MyPrecodedButton"     'important - code must exist ... see below
        .Object.Caption = "MyCaption"
        .Top = MyR_T
        .Left = MyR_L
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 18
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True            'or false as per your taste
    End With

End Sub
```

If - in advance - you have created following routine within the active sheet

```
Private Sub MyPrecodedButton_Click()
    MsgBox "Co-Cooo!"
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for me. Have you tried stepping through the code where `Call CreateDynamicButton` and see what happens?

Comment: How are you trying to call it? Where is `Call CreateDynamicButton`?

Comment: Thank for the help, the problem turned out to be the macro before the Button Macro, it ran but failed to call the next Macro which was the button Macro.

Answer (score 0):

In your VB Editor, in the project explorer (left pane) right click your current project and choose Insert->module. Paste your code in the new module (module1).

Where ever you want your CreateDynamicButton sub routine to be called from type Call CreateDynamicButton.

Example to call from another button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call CreateDynamicButton
End Sub
```

Comment: Ryan, Thank for the help, the problem turned out to be the macro before the Button Macro, it ran but failed to call the next Macro which was the button Macro.