# Assign macro to a programmatically added vba button

Tags: excel, vba, button

I try to programmatically adding a VBA button to my workbook.
I can creat it but for some reason I can't link a macro on it.

I always get the error message :

> Cannot run the macro "xxx". the macro may not be available in this WB or all macros may be disabled

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Remove all old buttons of the worksheet
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
'Restore Folder selector button
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1))
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With btn
    .OnAction = "FolderSelector"
    .Caption = "Folder selector"
    .Name = "Folder Selector"
End With
End Sub

Sub FolderSelector()
 MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

Is there anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: Is `Sub FolderSelector()` in a module or in `ThisWorkbook` scope as the `Workbook_Open`? The `Sub FolderSelector()` must be in a module and defined as `Public Sub FolderSelector()`

Comment: Put the `FolderSelector` routine in a normal module, not in `ThisWorkbook`. Also make sure the module is not called `FolderSelector` too!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys !! it was the good solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621960/vba-excel-2010-how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-command-button-that-was-made-with-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following syntax to avoid odd naming issues:

**In `ThisWorkbook`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Remove all old buttons of the worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    'Restore Folder selector button
    Dim t As Range
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) 'note this is shorter and the same as .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1))

    Dim btn As Object
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

    With btn
        .OnAction = "FolderSelectorButton_Click"
        .Caption = "Folder selector"
        .Name = "FolderSelectorButton"
    End With
End Sub
```

**In a module `CommandButtonActions`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FolderSelectorButton_Click()
   MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

The procedure you call from the button has to be in a normal module and it has to be `Public` (which is actually default).